# Concat two url in java

Tags: java

I have a base url string and another string which should be appended to the base url to get the exact url to request.
currently i am using string manipulation to achieve the result. The code i implemented is as follows

```
private String getUrl(String base, String className){
        try{
            if(!base.endsWith("/")){
                base= base + "/";
            }
            base= base+ base;
            return base;
        }
```

Is there any inbuilt method to concat the two string directly?

Comment: I asked about any url methods to do that like as answer specified by @isnot2bad

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `java.net.URI` class:

```
URI baseURI = new URI(base + "/");
URI fullURI = baseURI.resolve(className);

URL url = fullURI.toURL(); // as URL
String urlString = fullURI.toString(); // as String
```

Especially if you can pre-create the base `URI` once and reuse it multiple times!